# What's the magic path for npm when using sudo?

Tags: sudo, npm

I remember I was able to use something like `sudo ${which npm} run xxx` when I needed root privilege to run npm. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash you can do

```sh
sudo "$(which npm)" run ...

# or

sudo "`which npm`" run ...
```

Comment: yes but it will say node not found

Comment: @AeroWindwalker By default `sudo` will pass the `PATH` variable down to the child process, but sudo's security policy can override that. Assuming `which node` works before running sudo, you may need to add `Defaults env_keep += "PATH"` to your sudoers file (by running `sudo visudo`). See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables) and sudo's [man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html). If that works you may drop the `which` trick entirely.